# React Native load custom font only once

Tags: react-native, fonts

I want to load a custom font only once(maybe during app loading) and use it anywhere inside my app. Currently I'm loading the font using async-await method on every page that uses it. Can this be done in react native? 
Thanks.

Comment: are you using expo?

Comment: Yes. I am using expo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using Expo ? In that case, it should be easy in you App.js (or the first file load of your app)

You can see the example below :

```
import { Font } from 'expo'

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      fontLoaded: false
    }
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    try {
      await Font.loadAsync({
        MyFontName: require('./path/my-font.otf'),
        MyFontName2: require('./path/my-font-2.otf')
      })
      this.setState({ fontLoaded: true })
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
      return
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { fontLoaded } = this.state

    if (fontLoaded) {
      return (
        <View>
          <Text>Fonts are loaded !</Text>
        </View>
      )
    }

    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Loading fonts ...</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

After that, you can use the font's name in all styles of your app.

```
MyCustomStyle: {
  fontFamily: 'MyFontName'
}
```

Hope that can help you

Answer (score 0):

1) Add all the font files you want to an “assets/fonts” folder in the root of your react native project
2) Next, we need to tell React Native where our custom fonts are located. We do this by adding rnpm to package.json providing the path to the font files:

```js
"rnpm": {
  "assets": [
    "./assets/fonts/"
   ]
 },
```

3) Then we tell react native to link those font files for us:
    react-native link

4) This should add the font references in your Info.plist file for iOS and on Android copy the font files to android/app/src/main/assets/fonts. You can verify this by opening up Info.plist from the iOS folder and looking for a UIAppFonts key, you should see something similar to:

```html
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
 <array>
  <string>SF-Pro-Display.ttf</string>
 </array>
```

5) On Android, if you look in the file path “android/app/src/main/assets/fonts/” you should see your fonts have been copied over

6) With your fonts embedded and referenced it’s a simple case of adding them to your React Native styles. Simply add a fontFamily property with your font name:

```js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      justifyContent: "center",
      alignItems: "center",
      backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF"
    },
    heading: {
       fontFamily: "SF-Pro-Display-Bold",
       fontSize: 20,
       letterSpacing: 0,
       color: "#000000",
  },
    inputText: {
       fontFamily: "SF-Pro-Display-Medium",
       fontSize: 16,
       letterSpacing: 0,
       color: "#000000",
  },
 });
```

Comment: Your solution is not solving the problem of loading the font before the app Loads...